# Using classes in android - working with Context and helper classes

Tags: java, android

I am still newbie to android, please could someone help.

I want to use methods from the **Net** class as follows:

```
package com.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyApp extends Activity {

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  private Net wifi;

  TextView textStatus;    

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    wifi=new Net(this);
    textStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text); 
    textStatus.append("Your online status is ");

    if (wifi.isOnline()) {
      textStatus.append("online "+wifi.getInfo());
    } else {
      textStatus.append("offline "+wifi.getInfo());
    }
  }
}
```

and my **Net class**:

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class Net {
  WifiManager wifi;
  ConnectivityManager cm;
  NetworkInfo netInfo;

  public Net (Context ctx) {
    cm = (ConnectivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(ctx.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    wifi = (WifiManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
  }

  public boolean isOnline() { 
    netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  public NetworkInfo[] getName() {
    NetworkInfo[] name=cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
    return name;    
  }

  public String getInfo() {
    // Get WiFi status
    WifiInfo info = wifi.getConnectionInfo();
    return info.getSSID().toString();
  }
}
```

I believe I should not be extending my Net class with Activity? I am getting source not found error when running the app.

Comment: It looks like your first code sample is missing a few lines at the top.

Comment: which resource is not found? generally you have to extend activity at least in one of your class.

Comment: You must define all the activities from your code in the Android Manifest file of your application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I believe I should not be extending my
>   Net class with Activity?

Correct!

Your **Net** class is simply **a helper** so can be simply defined as:

```
public class Net {

  public Net (Context ctx) {
    cm = (ConnectivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
  }

  // Your other methods here...
}
```

When you create your `wifi` object, use `wifi = new Net(this);`

The Activity class in Android is used to provide a UI framework for visual/interactive elements such as buttons, textviews etc. etc. - basically anything the user needs to interact with. This isn't appropriate for your **Net** class.

Comment: if I do not extend it from Activity or Service it does not recognise getSystemService method :(

Comment: @Alanagh: See my edited code example for your Net class. If you pass the Activity context to the Net class, you should be able to use ctx.getSystemService().

Comment: Indeed, MisterSquonk is correct. Because the Activity class extends Context, you can call methods like getSystemService on the current object. Elsewhere, you need a context - but you can always provide this to other classes as per the example above. +1

Comment: Thank you MisterSquonk for your detailed explanation. However, it still does not except the getSystemService if Service is not extended.. but then in eclipse it suggest to "add unimplemented method" and the same error :((( . I have edited the code above as advised. Really appreciate your help.